# Neo4J 3.0 overlapping transactions

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-node

I am using Neo4j v3.0.6 with neo4j-driver 1.1.0-M2 (BOLT) and am experiencing the following behaviour where everytime two transactions overlap the second one fails. Is that expected behaviour? It looks weird to me given they are also in different session and they access different data.

- session1 = db.session()
- txn1 = session1.beginTransaction()
- session2 = db.session()
- txn2 = session2.beginTransaction()
- txn1.commit()
- txn2.commit() -> Fails with signature 126 and no other message